# rtl8192cu and Alfa AWUS036NHR v2 cannot connect to any network

Tags: wireless, drivers

Problem: it does not connect to any wifi network you can see the time out on dmesg

```
$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0bda:817f Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188RU 802.11n WLAN Adapter

$ iwconfig

wlp0s20u1  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

`$ dmesg`

http://pastebin.com/VJEWc2tQ

Comment: The driver in question is actually *rtl8192cu* and I have edited the title of your question to so reflect.

Comment: Actually the module is called rtl8xxxu and i think it is a rewritten driver for the new kernel 4.4.x that I am using. It is actualy very newand stable for only few devices. http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.wireless.general/143417 I am using this one beacuse the old one dropped connection after 10-15 mins

Answer (score 0):

The kernel driver for this adapter is quite unstable. I suggest that you install a better driver from source.

The newer driver has been packaged to DKMS format and added it to ppa. If you install it from there, you will not need to re-install it after kernel upgrades. It can be installed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: installed it and tried it without success